# Navigating to different screens from listTile

Tags: flutter, dart

How to Navigating to different screens from listTile

i am try to make a list tile inside it expansion tile contain elements but i acant to navigate to different screen how i can to do it in list title if you have a response leave it to me here

Comment: Please include your code too. Provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example of an ExpansionTile with one ListTile as a child**

```
ExpansionTile(
          title: Text('ExpansionTile 1'),
          subtitle: Text('Trailing expansion arrow icon'),
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text('This is tile number 1'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => NewPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
```